# Restrict Text Box to only accept 10 digit number

Tags: string, visual-studio, c++-cli

I have a Text Box that is a `System::String^`, I need to confirm that this only accepts 10 digits numbers and no letters, symbols, etc. How would I implement this in C++ visual studio?  Do I need to convert the contents to a `std::string` first?

Comment: +1 for introducing to me the '^' symbol in the context of C++

Comment: FYI, next time you post C++ code with '^' near a type, indicate that this is Microsoft's Managed C++.  In *standard* C++, the '^' is not a valid token after a type designator.

Comment: The proper name for that language is C++/CLI, and the tag is "c++-cli". "Managed C++" is a different set of C++ extensions (with keywords such as `__gc` and `__interface`) that was implemented by VC++2002 and VC++2003. It is incompatible with C++/CLI, and was replaced by the latter from VC++2005 on. Also, unlike MC++, C++/CLI has a proper public specification document (Ecma-372).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a .NET winforms text box (since your snippet is C++/CLI), you want to set the "MaxLength" property.  (Something like `TextBox^ tb = gcnew TextBox(); tb->MaxLength = 10`.)

For the numbers-only part, you want to assign a delegate to the KeyDown and KeyPress events to make sure the entered character is a number.  Sample Code is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: It makes no sense to link to VS 7.1 documentation when talking about C++/CLI.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(VS.100).aspx

Better?