# What is the "^" symbol in C++?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

Has a new symbol joined the C++ language specification while I was sleeping under a rock?

I just encountered the following question:

[Restrict Text Box to only accept 10 digit number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621649/restrict-text-box-to-only-accept-10-digit-number-c)

Which suggests that the '^' symbol is somehow part of C++ (not in the legacy meaning of a bitwise-XOR)

Is this so?

If so, what does it mean? (I tried to [google the question](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=what+is+the+%22%5E%22+symbol+in+vistual+C%2B%2B&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=7db4f7af4a13aa89) but Google didn't come up with satisfactory answers)

Comment: If you like `^`, you'll love that they also replaced `&` with `%` for references to managed types.  It's like they just decided screw it, let's just invent new operators and still call the language "C++".

Comment: @Ken Simon:  Since when does C++ have managed types?  C# has managed types, but not *standard* C++.

Comment: @Ken: the language is not called C++, it's called C++/CLI. One reason why it's called thus might be that plain C++ is a complete subset of C++/CLI (i.e. any conformant C++ program is also a conformant C++/CLI program).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In C++ the “^” symbol is the bitwise exclusive or (xor) operator. For a single bit you have `0 ^ 0 = 1 ^ 1 = 0` and `0 ^ 1 = 1 ^ 0 = 1`.

However, in the question you are refering to it is part of Microsoft special syntax for C++ development on the .NET platform known as C++/CLI or *It Just Works*.

Memory on .NET is garbage collected and references to objects will have to be tracked. This makes it impossible to reference these objects using a normal C++ pointer. Microsoft has decided to reuse the “^” symbol to declare a variable somewhat similar to a pointer that can reference an object on the managed heap.

[^ (Handle to Object on Managed Heap)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08.aspx)

Answer (score 19):

In Visual C++, `^` represents a handle to a managed object. Essentially what in C# would be a reference. Allocate them with `gcnew` instead of `new`, and they will be garbage collected for you. This is how Visual C++ interacts with the CLI.

Answer (score 11):

In the referenced answer, it's not part of the standard C++ language, it's part of the C++/CLI language that Microsoft cobbled together for .NET interop.  In that language, ^ means a "pointer to managed memory."

Answer (score 4):

The '^' syntax refers to a [tracking reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8903062a(VS.80).aspx) in [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), a Microsoft extension to C++ which enables interaction with managed code.

Comment: No, it's not.  `%` is a tracking reference.  `^` is a tracking handle.  (Read the page you linked to.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not part of Standard C++.  It's part of Managed C++ (Microsoft's language much like C++ for .NET).  It means "a reference to ----" in much the same way a "*" means "A pointer to -----" is Standard C++.

Comment: It is part of standard C++, in which it is the bitwise XOR operator.

Comment: Yeah, and "*" also means "multiply" but that's not what we are talking about here.

Comment: Double no.  `^` is a **tracking handle** to ----  Reference means something else in C++, and `%` is the managed equivalent to the standard C++ reference `&`.  And this is in C++/CLI.  In the defunct "Managed Extensions for C++", it was written as `__gc *` meaning garbage collector compatible pointer.